# Is it possible to insert a rdfs:subClassOf triple into a datastore?

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl

I have a slightly weird query and it's been bugging me. I have an application where I need to generate sub-concepts (owl:subClassOf) on the fly and store them in the dataset so that individuals can be instantiated against them dynamically. The following snippet generates a new concept called "Arduino" which is a subClassOf another ontological concept.

`datafeed:Arduino rdfs:subClassOf ssn:System.`

I tried inserting this into my TDB datastore using JENA. I get no errors, but I'm not sure if this even right. Can we insert subclasses into a datastore, or is a datastore only capable of containing individuals (i.e. instances of classes)? I seem to be going round and round in my head regarding this issue. I tried various SPARQL queries but I can't seem to work out if the triple above was stored in the dataset or not. I tried the following query to see if the concept was stored in the dataset but it returned no results:

```
SELECT ?concept
WHERE {
    ?concept a owl:Class.
}
```

Which is leading me to believe that results are only returned for individuals, and not class definitions...?

It's all a bit jumbled in my head. If someone can correct my understanding, then that would be wonderful.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jena (or indeed any triplestore I know of) stores all triples you add to it. Whether your triple involves a `rdfs:subClassOf` relation or not makes no difference.

Whether or not it performs any sort of reasoning on the data you store is another matter. This depends on the tool you use and the configuration you have chosen. The query that you do assumes that some form of reasoning has taken place: `datafeed:Arduino` will only be an `owl:Class` as a result of the insertion of the `rdfs:subClassOf` triple if you have inference enabled (and even then it will by default only infer that it's an instance of `rdfs:Class`, not necessarily of `owl:Class`).

A surefire way to test that your triple was inserted, without depending on reasoning, is to actually query for the specific triple, instead of its implied consequences, like so:

```
SELECT ?concept
WHERE { ?concept rdfs:subClassOf ssn:System . }
```

This will return all concepts that are a subclass of `ssn:System` - if your triple was properly insered, `datafeed:Arduino` will be in the result.

Or, perhaps even simpler:

```
ASK WHERE { datafeed:Arduino rdfs:subClassOf ssn:System . }
```

This will return `true` if the triple exists in the store, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Or even simpler yet: `ASK { datafeed:Arduion rdfs:subClassOf ssn:System }`.  (No need for `WHERE` or a trailing dot.) :)

Comment: Thank you Joshua. For some reason though, it's returning "no" meaning that the triple was not inserted... I'll have to investigate further. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Did you spot that there was a typo (now fixed) in the ASK query (Arduion instead of Arduino)? If you copy-pasted it without fixing that typo it would return false.